# Слайдер по клику на блоки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Изучаю `javascript` но пока не могу решить задачку со слайдером, алгоритм в голове есть, а руками написать не могу, всё время ошибки сыпятся.

Принцип такой кликнули на **1** блок он показался, кликнули на **2** блок он тоже показался и т.д.

```js
let element = document.querySelectorAll(`.gallery__image`);
let currentSlide = element[0];

for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  element[i].addEventListener(`click`, function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    currentSlide.classList.remove(`active-slide`);
    this.classList.add(`active-slide`);

    currentSlide = this;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery__box-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.gallery__image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  display: none;
}
.image-1 {
  background: red;
}
.image-2 {
  background: yellow;
}
.image-3 {
  background: green;
}
.gallery__big-image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}
.active-slide {
  border: solid 3px blue;
}
.gallery__big-image .active-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__box-image">
    <div class="gallery__image image-1 active-slide">1</div>
    <div class="gallery__image image-2">2</div>
    <div class="gallery__image image-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__big-image">
    <div class="image image-1 active-slide">1</div>
    <div class="image image-2">2</div>
    <div class="image image-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Лучше показать попытки и ошибки и объяснить, что именно не получается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
/*$('.gallery__image').click(function(e) {
  $('.gallery__big-image .image').removeClass('active-slide');
  $('.' + $(this).data('image')).addClass('active-slide');
}).eq(0).click();*/

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__box-image .gallery__image');
let bigImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__big-image .image');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    bigImgs.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active-slide'));
    document.querySelector('.gallery__big-image .image.' + this.dataset.image).classList.add('active-slide');
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__box-image {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.gallery__image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.image {
  display: none;
}

.image-1 {
  background: red;
}

.image-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.image-3 {
  background: green;
}

.gallery__big-image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}

.gallery__big-image .active-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__box-image">
    <div data-image="image-1" class="gallery__image image-1">1</div>
    <div data-image="image-2" class="gallery__image image-2">2</div>
    <div data-image="image-3" class="gallery__image image-3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__big-image">
    <div class="image image-1">1</div>
    <div class="image image-2">2</div>
    <div class="image image-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно на нативном js? Всё таки хочется узнать в чём была ошибка

Comment: @Дмитрий можно ссылку на нативный js ?